# How can I connect more than 2 drives to the Highpoint Rocket Raid 620

Tags: raid, sata

The raid card in question has only 2 sata ports on the card. I'd like to connect 5 drives to this, and I was wondering how I could achieve that.

The highpoint website states that up to 10 drives can be connected to the card, and hence I assume that up to 5 can be connected to each port on the card.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you want a [SATA Port Multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_multiplier).  This allows you to connect multiple SATA devices to a single SATA socket - provided the IO controller supports it.  It sounds like yours does.  Check with the manufacturer first before you invest cash in this though.

Comment: Where can I find a port multiplier that doesn't take up a PCI slot? I had assumed that I'd need one of these, but I wasn't able to find one anywhere that didn't take up a PCI slot.

Comment: http://www.google.com/products/catalog?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=sata+port+multiplier&oe=utf-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=15598644977072273254&sa=X&ei=rAaaTdDLA4-ChQfoqLWyBA&ved=0CEAQ8wIwAg# - while it takes up an expansion slot in the case it doesn't take up an actual motherboard slot.  You don't have to mount it in a slot, you could remove the bracket and mount it anywhere you like.